# Optimal algorithm of a separating hyperplane

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, combinatorial-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-geometry

What is an optimal algorithm for finding a separating hyperplane of two nonintersecting convex hulls of two sets of finite number of points?